# What's the best site to check timings and fares between two points in the NRW area in Germany?

Tags: germany

What's the best site to check timings and fares between two points in the NRW area in Germany by public transport?

Comment: NRW doesn't have a single bus fares area. You have to be more specific. Train fares and both bus and train timetables can be checked on the http://bahn.de website.